# Need A Valid Download link - Actionscript Remoting Components

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to find the "**Actionscript Remoting Components**" download on the internet but no use.. The adobe.com has seems to have a broken link for it.
Please share the web link if any other source you could find on the internet.

*I am trying to connect Flash to MySQL via PHP scripts for my flash based application.*

Thanks!!!

Comment: Could you find the remoting components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used **AMFPHP** as remoting component with actionScript to Connect with Php and MySQL.
you can see detail documentation to http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/documentation/ link

good luck!

Comment: Thanks ! I thought it might be using the Actionscript Remoting Components but it is a nice framework. Although surprised that it is not demanding the Components installed.. ??? 
But hope that AMFPHP documentation would be easier. Thanks!!!